Best way to query huge linked server tables in local database?
I have 2 database servers, 1 is used locally by a website I maintain, the other is a server for a CMS/data warehouse which stores data internally for my company's sales reps. I need to pull data from both, currently I'm using linked servers but this can be incredibly slow for some queries, for example:
SELECT count(DISTINCT o.order_id) as c
FROM   orders o
       INNER JOIN cart_contents cc
               ON o.order_id = cc.order_id
       INNER JOIN products pr
               ON pr.product_id = cc.product_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [CMS_DB_SERVER].[MAIN_DB].[dbo].[invoices] sl 
                    ON  o.order_number = sl.order_number
                       AND pr.item_number = sl.item_number
                       AND cc.line_number = sl.line_number
WHERE  ( o.cancelled = 0 )
       AND ( sl.invoice_status < 2 )

In this case querying [CMS_DB_SERVER].[MAIN_DB].[dbo].[invoices] causes this to run for 5+ minutes. Removing the linked server table lets the query run in just 5 seconds, although that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. This table is also 11 gb in size with almost 100 million records, and I constantly need to provide data that's less than 1 hour old, so making a copy of this table locally isn't feasible.
What's the best way to handle this without having such a big performance hit?
Here's an index the linked table has, it covers the 3 fields used on the join:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_cnt_invoices] ON [dbo].[invoices]
(
    [order_number] ASC,
    [item_number] ASC,
    [line_number] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) 

(Also yes I know SQL server 2008 is bad as this is mentioned in every question I post, we are migrating to 2022 in a few months)

For SQL performance questions we need at a minimum: tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Also if you could tell us the number of rows that qualify for o.cancelled = 0 and sl.invoice_status < 2 as well as the total, out of each table.

@Charlieface I was hoping there's a better solution than to continue use a linked server. There's an index that covers all the joined fields, I added it to my post.

Also there are about 150,000 rows for o.cancelled = 0 and 600,000 for sl.invoice_status < 2

Sql server cannot inner loop join the linked server tables, so it has to bring everything upfront. Your left join makes little sense though, since your where condition turns it into an inner join, making the whole query feel a bit suspect. Not sure much can be done, sometimes one can reverse the query so that it ran from linked server which allows it to fetch less data perhaps

Well the best solution is to have all the tables on a single server (even if it's different databases), but I'm guessing you don't want that. Either way, we need all the info I asked otherwise this question is not answerable.

@siggemannen The server can loop join a linked server, but it's often not worth it.
